# Rails 4 Strong Parameters test logging of Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Does anyone know how to test the logging of Unpermitted parameters using Rspec.

I have tried using Rails.logger.should_receive() with :warn, :info, :error but I can't seem to capture the log message.

Here is the controller test:

```
describe Api::V2::ItemsController do

  before do
    @item = FactoryGirl.create(:item)
    @user_id = @item.user_id
    @invalid_user_id = @user_id + 1
  end

  it 'should not assign user_id' do
    put :update, id: @item.id, item: { user_id: @invalid_user_id }
    assigns(:item).user_id.should == @user_id
  end

  it 'should write "Unpermitted parameters: user_id" to log' do
    Rails.logger.should_receive(:warn).with("Unpermitted parameters: user_id")
    put :update, id: @item.id, item: { user_id: @invalid_user_id }
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried `:debug`?

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/actionpack/lib/action_controller/log_subscriber.rb#L53

You could also try `expect(ActionController::Base.logger).to receive(:debug).with('...')`.

Comment: Pablo, I can't believe it. That was it. Write it as an answer and I will give you the bounty. On a related note do you know of a way to change the log level to warn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with [:debug](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/actionpack/lib/action_controller/log_subscriber.rb#L53)?

```ruby
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:debug).with('...')
# or
# expect(ActionController::Base.logger).to receive(:debug).with('...')
```

To change the log level to warn you could try the config below in any of your environment files.

```ruby
# config/environments/development.rb
# config/environments/production.rb
config.log_level = :warn
```

More: [Debugging Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels)